# How to sum the numbers I see in the array and not all the numbers between them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I have built this function hoping to sum the numbers I assign to the array. However, this function gives not only the sum of the numbers I put in the array but also those in between them and I am not sure how to fix that

```
 function sum(arr) {
    let total = 0;

    let start = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
    let end = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);

    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      total += i;
    }
    return total;
  }
```

for example this console.log(sum([2,4])); gives 9 and not 6

Also, I cannot seem to find a way to be able to add more than two numbers to my array

Comment: Could you elaborate please? With some more examples.

Comment: hmmm... do you just want to sum two numbers, like `arr[0] + arr[1]`?

Comment: 0+2+3+4 is 9 not 6?

Comment: @ Prateek Thapa I want to make a function with an array as a parameter, and when I call the function and I put, for example [2, 3, 7], I want to receive the sum of these 3 numbers which is 12, and not the sum of the numbers from 2 till 7

Comment: @StavAk then don’t sum `i`. Sum the values in the array instead.

Comment: @ James unfortunately no because I am supposed to make a function

Comment: @ evolutionxbox  I do not want to have a 9. I want 6 but for the time being my function gives 9. How could I fix it